# How to Add Visualforce Pages to Page Layout?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

How come I do not have the option to select a visual force page as an option for my page layout? I want to be able to use a visual force page for the page layout because I want to list the (a custom object) products selected for the service case (which also is a custom object) layout.

[image]

In the salesforce documentation it says there should be a visual force page field in the left column: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/overrides_2.htm

Also here is an example where another user has the option while I do not.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only get this option if there are `Visualforce Pages` available that implement the correct controller. If you see a page like this in your org, you should have the option enabled.

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c">
```

This `StandardController` implementation also enables you to use the `Visualforce Page` in `Detail Buttons`.

There may be other attributes. The only one that is relevant is `recordSetVar`. If this attribute is set (to any value), then it implements `StandardSetController` instead of `StandardController` and can be used in `List Buttons` instead.