# How to assign custom buttons conditionally for Contacts in Salesforce application

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-button, salesforce-classic

I am new to Salesforce. I have added two custom buttons XXX & YYY in my Salesforce application. But I want to assign these two buttons based on conditions for different contacts.

For example: If the contact is related to Firm 'A' then we need to show only the custom button XXX in the contact layout, for contacts related to other firms should be able to see only the custom button YYY in the contact layout.

Please help me with how to implement the above requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a use case for Dynamic Actions. Some nice explanation here: https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-dynamic-actions-overview/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement [dynamic action](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-dynamic-actions-overview/) in your case record lightning page.

**How:** To enable dynamic actions for a custom object on desktop and mobile, add or select the Highlights Panel component on the object’s record page. In the Highlights Panel properties pane, click Upgrade Now and step through the migration assistant to migrate actions or start with new ones.

To add an action in any of the dynamic actions scenarios, click **Add Action (1)** in the properties pane. In the Actions modal, choose an action and click **Add Filter (2)** to assign visibility rules based on record field, device type, and other filters. An eye icon Eye icon indicates visibility rules are appled to action. **(3) next to an action’s name** indicates that visibility rules are applied. If you migrated actions from a page layout, you can modify them in the Actions modal.

[image]

Checkout this help page:- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lex_dynamic_actions_desktop_mobile.htm&type=5&release=230

Comment: Just to point out that this is only an option for a limit number of standard objects, and then only for the desktop experience. Dynamic actions are fully supported on custom objects. See the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_app_builder_create_dynamic_action.htm&type=5) for a list of where you can use them. Also note that these only work in Lightning (I note the question tag "salesforce-classic").

Comment: @sanket kumar Thanks for your response. Clicking on Upgrade Now will charge any extra in terms of pricing. Please suggest

Comment: @PhilW You are right. I need this functionality for both classic and lightning expierience.

Comment: There's no additional cost for using dynamic actions. To address this in Classic, you will likely have to do this the old fashioned way and write your own Visualforce page to include in the page layout (there may be other options).

Comment: @PhilW Could you please help me to address this in Classic with some examples? I am not sure how to do that as I am new to Salesforce. Thanks

Comment: There's stuff out there that will help. First write the Visualforce page (and Controller) to provide the button(s) you want, following the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_creating_pages), understanding you need to do this for the correct object - [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136535/how-to-add-visualforce-pages-to-page-layout) discusses that a bit. It's a shame you need to support Classic since this is all very old tech and not something you probably want to learn!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help